# Is Communication Through Private IP Of 2 VPS On The Same Region Faster Than Communication Through Their Public IP?

Tags: networking, instance, vps, ipv4, linode

So, I have two instances on Linode. Both of them came with a public IP and a private IP. I'm using one instance as my application backend and other as database server. Now I'm wondering by which IP it is better to connect to the database instance from backend one. Will there be any speed difference even in micro second scale?

Answer (score 0):

In the "micro second scale", possibly, depending on how the network is configured. More importantly though, using the private IP is safer. Given the opportunity, you should never have a database serving on a public IP address.